# How to create a UITableView only?

Tags: iphone

Can i create a table by using only a UITableView without a UITableViewController?
Is it possible, if it so how to do that programatically?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand -- what is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a application with UITableView without using a Controller i.e. only with views. Can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if you could tell us what is the reason you want to use UITableView instead of UITableViewController?

I believe that you can use UITableView and not the UITableViewContoller, but in this case you need to set appropraite delegates (`dataSource` and `delegate`) which need to comply with appropriate protocols. 
For more information have a look at the documentation at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
UITableView *table =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
                                               style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

// Other initializations go here
[parent_view addSubview: table];
[table release];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me..Now how should i add UITableViewCell to the UITableView?